# OpenCV overlay 2 image based on image mask

Tags: python, opencv

I need overlay 2 images based on third image mask

Example
1.-I have this background

[image: background]

2.-I have this object image and also i have de segmentation image

Object image
[image]

I'm try to merge Backgound and Object image based on third image (mask image)

(mask image)
[image]

The final result is Background image + Object image(only based on mask)
Any idea..
I tried

```
import cv2
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(back_img,0.4,aug_demoimage,0.1,0)
```

But not working as expected.. any sugestion? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Solved

```
def get_only_object(img, mask, back_img):
    fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask)        
    #imshow(fg)
    # invert mask
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)    
    #fg_back = cv2.bitwise_or(back_img, back_img, mask=mask)
    fg_back_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(back_img, back_img, mask=mask_inv)
    #imshow(fg_back_inv)
    final = cv2.bitwise_or(fg, fg_back_inv)
    #imshow(final)

    return final
```

Comment: fair warning: this will work for cases where all the images have the same dimensions. If that is your use case, then this should work well

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the object image into an RGBA image where the alpha channel is the mask image you have created. Once you do this, you can paste it to the background image.

```
def convert_to_png(img, a):
    #alpha and img must have the same dimenstons

    fin_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
    b, g, r, alpha = cv2.split(fin_img)
    alpha = a
#    plt.imshow(alpha);plt.title('alpha image');plt.show()
#    plt.imshow(img);plt.title('original image');plt.show()
#    plt.imshow(alpha);plt.title('fin alpha image');plt.show()
    fin_img[:,:, 0] = img[:,:,0]
    fin_img[:,:, 1] = img[:,:,1]
    fin_img[:,:, 2] = img[:,:,2]
    fin_img[:,:, 3] = alpha[:,:]
#    plt.imshow(fin_img);plt.title('fin image');plt.show()
    return fin_img
```

This function will combine the two images into an RGBA image.

```
y1, y2 = new_loc[1], new_loc[1] + img.shape[0]
x1, x2 = new_loc[0], new_loc[0] + img.shape[1]

alpha_s = img[:, :, 3] / 255.0
alpha_l = 1.0 - alpha_s

for c in range(0, 3):
    fin_img[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = (alpha_s * img[:, :, c] +
                              alpha_l * img[y1:y2, x1:x2, c])
```

And this will copy the Object image to the background image